# error EGLFS enabled but pre-condition fail, installing qt on Rpi3

Tags: c++, qt, raspberry-pi3

im trying to compile from source Qt 5.15.8 LTS into my rpi3, i did updated/upgraded and follow all the steps of [this](https://www.tal.org/tutorials/building-qt-515-lts-raspberry-pi-raspberry-pi-os) tutorial, but i cant compile if i use the -opengl and -eglfs options, every time i get the same error **Feature "eglfs" was enabled, but the pre-condition failed** , same for opengl, i can configure/compile as long i dont use those 2 options, but sadly when i try to run any compiled program using the qt lybraries i get the follow error **qt.qpa.plugin: could not find the qt platform plugin "xcb" in ""** same for eglfs, and only give me 4 options, linuxfb, minimal, offscreen, vnc

i did read somewhere that the problem might be a conflict betwen the broadcom and meza libraries, but im using a rpi3 and installed the latest os from the rpi page.

i have been checking every tutorial, example and qt forum to no avail, honestly i start to believe that using qt on rpi3 is imposible, as anyone ever been capable of compiling and running apps on the rpi3?

note: im using vscode+cmake via ssh from my laptop to the rpi and it works ok, the only problem is that im unable to start any window on the rpi screen.

no mather if i use any of the follow, i cant configure, i have to remove all of them in order for configure script to work ***-eglfs -opengl -xcb***

**EDIT**, forgot to add the output of the compile as well my compile configuration

**EDIT2** while checking the installed programs on my rpi3 i did found i have by default installed qt gui module(***libqt5gui5-5.15.2+dfsg-9+rpi1***) as well others but they seems to be libraries, theres anyway to use those to compile using vscode instead of the header files?, that way i might avoid compiling from scracht the entire qt framework, last time took me like 40 hours to fully compile

Configuration
[image]

if i try to compile using the ***-eglfs*** i get the follow error
[image]

when i check if eglfs is aviable its not (QPA Backends)
[image]

if i compile without the opengl and eglfs i can create programs but im unable to run it and get the next error
[image]

Comment: Can you post the entire output? Doesn't it say what pre-condition failed?

Comment: @LucaCarlon, done forgot to add the images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is the version of Qt provided by Raspberry OS, then you can probably get away with installing the dev packages:

```
sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools
```

I'm not sure if you are looking for the X11 version or the eglfs version though, this isn't clear.

Comment: i just want to show 1 window with the stream of 2 cameras, also if install those packages, they install the header files or the compiled libraries? i read about using the libraries but im clueless about how to use them, im using vscode+cmake via ssh, and i dont care about any especific, could be eglfs or x11, just want to see stuff on screen

Comment: Then this is probably the quickest way. Those packages should install the headers of the Qt core: https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/armhf/qtbase5-dev/filelist.

Comment: ok this seems to do the trick, now i got all the basic library, not sure if i need something else at this point im just looking into options, by the way where can i see a list of other packages related to qt5? it seems thres no information about what packages i can install on linux/rpi3

Comment: ill try to compile and run my program, not sure where to find the platform especific but i did installed the QtX11Extras library just in case,the one from the list that you shared above, thanks

Comment: apt-cache gives you the list of packages. If the answer is correct, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: at the end i was abble to install the Qt5 libraries, sadly im unable to run the program because i dont have the correct eglfs plugin, not sure where or how to find it, im switching to python and try something else, this is imposible on the rpi3, thanks

Comment: just a side note i did was abble to find the eglfs plugins and copied that into my program folder and setup a qt.conf file just to make sure it find the location, and even when it manages to find the platform plugin is unable to load it, using the export QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 just tell me **libqt5eglfsdeviceintegration.so.5 undefined symbol**

Comment: Are you sure you understand what eglfs is? If you want to create a window, it does not seem you want eglfs in any way. I suspect all you want is the xcb plugin. In the screenshots you uploaded you seem to be using X11, which means you do not want eglfs.